# How to get DataStream key after keyBy() in Flink Java API

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm reading from a Kafka cluster in a Flink streaming app. After getting the source stream i want to aggregate events by a composite key and a timeEvent tumbling window and then write result to a table.
The problem is that after applying my aggregateFunction that just counts number of clicks by clientId i don't find the way to get the key of each output record since the api returns an instance of accumulated result but not the corresponding key.

```
    DataStream<Event> stream = environment.addSource(mySource)

    stream.keyBy(new KeySelector<Event,Integer>() {
    public Integer getKey(Event event) { return event.getClientId(); })
.window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(1))).aggregate(new MyAggregateFunction)
```

How do i get the key that i specified before? I did not inject key of the input events in the accumulator as i felt i wouldn't be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than

```
.aggregate(new MyAggregateFunction)
```

you can use

```
.aggregate(new MyAggregateFunction, new MyProcessWindowFunction)
```

and in this case the process method of your ProcessWindowFunction will be passed the key, along with the pre-aggregated result of your AggregateFunction and a Context object with other potentially relevant info. See the section in the docs on [ProcessWindowFunction with Incremental Aggregation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#processwindowfunction-with-incremental-aggregation) for more details.